# Tracking and updating value in a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, tree

Found this code online which can be used to find the maximum value in a tree between two leaf nodes:

```
INT_MIN = -2**32

class Node: 
    def __init__(self, data): 
        self.data = data 
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def maxPathSumUtil(root, res): 
    if root is None: 
        return 0

    if root.left is None and root.right is None: 
        return root.data 

    ls = maxPathSumUtil(root.left, res) 
    rs = maxPathSumUtil(root.right, res) 

    # If both left and right children exist 
    if root.left is not None and root.right is not None:      
        res[0] = max(res[0], ls + rs + root.data) 
        return max(ls, rs) + root.data 

    # If any of the two children is empty, return 
    # root sum for root being on one side 
    if root.left is None: 
        return rs + root.data 
    else: 
        return ls + root.data 

def maxPathSum(root): 
        res = [INT_MIN] 
        maxPathSumUtil(root, res) 
        return res[0]
```

My question is in regards to `res[0]`. Why use a list with only one value to keep track of the maximum value at that node? I tried changing it to a regular integer and it does not get updated properly. It returns the wrong value. So why does using a list with a single value works versus using a regular integer to keep track of the maximum value during a recursive function?

Comment: When you assign to `res` you reassign it to refer to a different object. By passing a `list` you can instead modify the list. If you reassign `res` to a new list it also won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The `res` list acts as *reference* to the original object, so that even without returning the object, the function can *mutate* it.

<sub>Note: If you're familiar with C/C++, this is like passing a reference using `<type> &<var_name>` into the function.</sub>

The following example illustrates this:

```
>>> def func(ref):
...  ref.append(1)
... 
>>> list_ = [1, 2, 3]
>>> func(list_)
>>> list_
[1, 2, 3, 1]
```

As seen, the function changes the object **in-place**.

This is primarily due to `list_` and `ref` referring to the same `id`.

```
>>> def func(ref):
...  ref.append(1)
...  print('Ref:', id(ref))
... 
>>> list_ = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(list_)
4421621704
>>> func(list_)
Ref: 4421621704
```

Since both `list_` and `ref` refer to the same `id`, any changes to the list will propagate throughout other lists with the same `id`'s.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> b.append(10)
>>> id(a), id(b)
(4421619848, 4421619848)
>>> a, b
([1, 2, 3, 10], [1, 2, 3, 10])
```

Note that `a` and `b` have the same `id`, they thus refer to the same list object. This justifies why a `10` was appended to `a`.

Comment: I understand the function mutates it but why is it mutating it incorrectly? Isn't the function also "mutating" the list?

Comment: Err... where do you see the function mutating it "_incorrectly_"? Yes, the function is mutating the list, I've tried to make that clear in my answer.